# SocketIO: Update connected sockets from a URL

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a Node server with the following code in it:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var fs = require('fs');

function handler(request,response) {
    if (request.url == '/123') {
         // The following line says that socket is undefined.
         //socket.emit('case_updated', 123);
    }
    response.writeHead(200, {'Location' : '/'});
    return response.end('');
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('case_updated', function(caseNumber){
        socket.broadcast.emit('case_updated', caseNumber);
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Now I want to have the `socket.broadcast.emit` to be triggered, when that URL is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the question.

I just installed `socket.io-client` package in the same place where server, and instantiated the client within server code and I was able to play around with `socket.emit` function. In the handler function within if statement, I am making a client.

```
var server = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var fs = require('fs');

function handler(request,response) {
    if (request.url == '/123') {
        //192.168.2.100 is the ip of the same server where this code is located.
        var socket_client = require("socket.io-client")('http://192.168.2.100:3000');
        socket_client.on('connect', function () {
            socket_client.emit('case_updated', 123);
        });
    }
    response.writeHead(200, {'Location' : '/'});
    return response.end('');
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('case_updated', function(caseNumber){
        socket.broadcast.emit('case_updated', caseNumber);
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Another solution would have be the following : wrap your route handling in your `io.socket.on('connection')`. A bit less readable at first sight i guess, but prevent the use of another socket client.